# How to populate related list records in VF page for Editing?

Tags: visualforce, custom-object, custom-button, quote

I have a custom object as "Competitor__c" which has a lookup relation to Quote Object.I have a created a visualforce page on Competitor object to fetch related list record ,when user clicks on list button for editing.Now the issue is instead of getting the related list record of Competitor , i get all the records listed in my vf page related to competitor.Any Suggestion plz.

For Example :I have one quote record named as :QuotePDF and 2 related records of competitor.when the user clicks on the list button ,it should display only 2 records related to competitor for editing.

**Here is VISUAL FORCE Page :**

```
<apex:page standardcontroller="Competitor__c" sidebar="false" recordSetVar="Competitors" extensions="CompetitorEditExt" >
 <apex:form >
  <apex:sectionHeader title="Edit Competitors for" subtitle=""/>
   <apex:pageBlock id="comp">
     <apex:pageBlockButtons >
       <apex:commandButton value="SAVE" action="{!SAVE}"/>
       <apex:commandButton value="CANCEL" action="{!CANCEL}"/>
     </apex:pageBlockButtons>
       <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!comp}" var="c" rendered="{!NOT(ISNULL(comp))}">
         <apex:column value="{!c.Name}"/ >
         <apex:column value="{!c.Product_Series__c}"/ >
         <apex:column value="{!c.Part_Number__c}"/ >
         <apex:column headerValue="Price">
            <apex:inputField value="{!c.Price_Offered__c}"/>
         </apex:column>
         <apex:column headerValue="Volume">
            <apex:inputField value="{!c.Volume__c}"/>
         </apex:column>
         <apex:column value="{!c.Date_Price_is_Valid__c}"/ >
       </apex:pageBlockTable>
     </apex:pageBlock>
 </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**Apex Code :**

```
public with sharing class CompetitorEditExt {

    private List<Competitor__c> comp;
    //private Quote q;

    public CompetitorEditExt(ApexPages.StandardSetController controller) {
    controller.setPageSize(10);
   // this.q= (Quote)controller.getRecord();
}
    public List<Competitor__c> getcomp()
        {
            comp = [Select Id, Name, Part_Number__c, Price_Offered__c, Product_Series__c, Volume__c, Date_Price_is_valid__c from Competitor__c ];
            return comp;
        }
    public pageReference saveStatusChange(){
    update this.comp;
    return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Koen Wesselman:i have added my complete code of vf page

Comment: @KoenWesselman:I have made the necessary changes but it throws an ERROR as :System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject ,Class.CompetitorRelatedList.<init>: line 13, column 1,at this line :Compitetor__c currentComp = [SELECT CustomQuote__c FROM Compitetor__c WHERE Id = :currentCompId];

Comment: Is the name of your object "Compitetor__c"? I believe it should be "Competitor__c" instead, right?

Comment: @KoenWesselman:As of now i'm working in Developer Edition ,where my custom object was named as Compitetor__c".Whereas im my org its is Competitor__c.

Comment: Can you verify that this error shows on Competitor pages that definitely **do** have related Competitors as well as pages that definitely **do not** have related Competitors?

Comment: @KoenWesselman:I tried in my org edition,it throws me the error as System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject Class.CompetitorEditExt.getcomp: line 14, column 1.(i.e.Competitor__c currentComp = [SELECT Quote__c FROM Competitor__c WHERE Id = :currentCompId];).Similarly when i added list to the query ,it started throwing me another error as :Error: CompetitorEditExt Compile Error: Initial term of field expression must be a concrete SObject: LIST<Competitor__c> at line 16 column 164];{i.e.:comp = [Select Id, Name from Competitor__c WHERE Quote__c = :currentComp.Quote__c];}

Comment: Like I asked in previous comment: Can you please check whether the first error shows for Competitors with related Competitors and Competitors without related Competitors? :-)

Comment: @KoenWesselman:Im not getting your point.

Comment: Alright, this code looks for Competitor records that are related to the Competitor record you're currently viewing because they have the same Quote as parent. Correct?

Comment: @KoenWesselman:These Competitor records have different Quote as Parent and few competitor records does not have Quote as parent,but the competitor records get displayed in vf page.

Comment: Ah, I think I misunderstood your question. I've edited the code in my answer now, please try this solution.

Comment: @KoenWesselman:I tried replacing the code ,but the it does not display any of the records and the labels of the field gets disappeared.

Comment: Can you send me your current Apex code in pastebin.com? And tell me the name of the Quote field on the org you're testing on?

Comment: @KoenWesselman:Im looking something similar fuctionality like QuoteLineitems "EDITALL"button.which gives only the related records to edit from Quote parent record.

Comment: Alright, please do show me your current code so I can help you with that. I also need the name of the Quote look-up field on Competitor for the Org you're working on.

Comment: @KoenWesselman:I have sent the code in pastebin.com

Comment: You also need to post the link here, so I can see it :-)

Comment: @KoenWesselman:http://pastebin.com/HVAD2YCF

Comment: If you uncomment line 12 and line 16, and comment/remove line 18. What happens? Please add the lines: _System.debug(CustomQuoteId);_ and _System.debug(comp);_ and tell me what they show.

Comment: @KoenWesselman:I have Uncommented the line 12 and 16 ,commented the line 18,there are no records been displayed and the label names get disappeared.When checked in the debug log :USER_DEBUG|[13]|DEBUG|null,USER_DEBUG|[18]|DEBUG|()

Comment: On line 12, can you change _get('Id');_ to _get('id');_? Also, I presume there is a Salesforce ID in the URL? :-) Then, please tell me the results in the debug log again.

Comment: @KoenWesselman:I changed the get('id') but their is no difference.It gives me the same result in debug log.Their is no salesforce id dispalyed ,i could see only the instance followed with my vf page name

Comment: I've edited my answer, please try the code and make sure to mark it as the right answer by clicking the grey check if it works.

Comment: @KoenWesselman:I tried the below code ,it does not displays any of the records and the field labels get disappeared.Im looking something similar fuctionality like QuoteLineitems "EDITALL"button.which gives only the related records to edit from Quote parent record.For Example :I have one quote record named as :QuotePDF and its has 2  records of competitor named as comp1 and comp2 .when the user clicks on the list button(Edit all button on Competitor related list on quote object) ,it should display only the 2 records (comp1 and comp2) of competitor for editing.

Comment: Woops, made a small mistake, editted my solution. Please add debug lines to check whether _this.quoteId_ is set in the constructor if there's no Competitors visible.

Comment: Hey guys, for the record SFSE does have a chat option :)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19988/discussion-on-question-by-nikkey-how-to-populate-related-list-records-in-vf-page).

Comment: @KoenWesselman:I tried the code , i still get an Error as :
System.TypeException: Invalid conversion from runtime type SOBJECT:Competitor__c to SOBJECT:Quote.

Class.CompetitorEditExt.<init>: line 8, column 1

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19988/discussion-on-question-by-nikkey-how-to-populate-related-list-records-in-vf-page
Please join this chat so we can troubleshoot there :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you looked into the apex:relatedList tag yet? https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_relatedList.htm

If this is not a solution for you, please share your full VisualForce page. I think you've only copied the last two lines. You'll have a add a where-clause in your query based on the ID that you pass to the class in VisualForce.

**Update:**

Please replace your Apex code with:

```
public with sharing class CompetitorEditExt {

    private List<Competitor__c> comp;
    private Id quoteId;

    public CompetitorEditExt(ApexPages.StandardSetController c) {
        c.setPageSize(10);
        this.quoteId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
    }

    public List<Competitor__c> getcomp() {
        comp = [Select Id, Name, Part_Number__c, Price_Offered__c, Product_Series__c, Volume__c, Date_Price_is_valid__c from Competitor__c where CustomQuote__c = :this.quoteId];
        return comp;
    }

    public pageReference save() {
        update comp;
        PageReference ret = new PageReference(ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('retURL'));
        return ret.setRedirect(true);
    }

    public PageReference cancel() {
        PageReference ret = new PageReference(ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('retURL'));
        return ret.setRedirect(true);
    }

}
```

Now we use the Quote's Id to look for the Competitor records that are related to it. I've also made sure your save() and cancel() methods return to the original Quote.

Comment: Agreed.  Your SOQL statement isn't limited to the ID of the Quote, so you're returning all Competitor records.

Comment: @Koean Wesselman:Thanks for your priceless time and needful help.I really appreciate you help.